# Cannot pass array of objects into child component using React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I would like to pass an array of objects from parent component to child component, but when I pass as `props` and declare interface on child component with expected types parent component gives error. How can I pass the data?

Here is the code to pass prop to a child called ConsultationCard

```js
else if (check && st.length !== 0) {
   return <ConsultationCard itemData={items} />;
}
```

and parent component giving this error:

> Type '({ id: number; title: string; client: string; due: string; count: number; amount: number; method: string[]; material: string[]; status: string; docs?: undefined; } | { id: number; title: string; client: string; ... 6 more ...; count?: undefined; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Data[]'

Child component has this type of interface and prop expectation:

```js
interface Data {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  client: string;
  due: string;
  count: number;
  amount: number;
  method: string[];
  material: string[];
  status: string;
  docs?: number | undefined;
}
interface Props {
  itemData: Data[];
}
```

Comment: In the error message, it shows `count?: undefined`. That doesn't match up with your type `Data`. Also, don't do `docs?: number | undefined`. It's already marked as optional, you don't need to specify `| undefined`. It's redundant.

Comment: could you include an example of your `items`.

Comment: {
    "requests": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "자동차 시제품 제작",
        "client": "A 고객사",
        "due": "2020.12.14",
        "count": 2,
        "amount": 100,
        "method": ["밀링", "선반"],
        "material": ["알루미늄"],
        "status": "대기중"
      },                                                here is the data of items